# Jquery mouseenter mouseleaave issue

Tags: jquery, css

I've the mouseenter/mouseleave issue using jQuery, apparently when I pass the mouse over the child element it triggers the mouseleave action.

I have all the code in http://jsfiddle.net/theylooksotired/ucarF/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="menuAll">
  <div class="menuIns">
    <div class="menuInsTop">
      <a href="http://localhost/ilki/expertise">Expertise</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menuInsBottom" style="display: none;">
      <div class="menuInsBottomIns">
        <a href="http://localhost/ilki/expertise#notre-offre">Notre offre</a>
        <a href="http://localhost/ilki/expertise#conseil">Conseil</a>
        <a href="http://localhost/ilki/expertise#architecture">Architecture</a>
        <a href="http://localhost/ilki/expertise#formation">Formation</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menuIns">
    <div class="menuInsTop">
      <a href="http://localhost/ilki/carrieres">Carrierès</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menuInsBottom" style="display: none;">
      <div class="menuInsBottomIns">
        <a href="http://localhost/ilki/expertise#notre-offre">Notre offre</a>
        <a href="http://localhost/ilki/expertise#conseil">Conseil</a>
        <a href="http://localhost/ilki/expertise#architecture">Architecture</a>
        <a href="http://localhost/ilki/expertise#formation">Formation</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menuIns">
    <div class="menuInsTop">
      <a href="http://localhost/ilki/a-propos">A propos</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menuInsBottom" style="display: none;">
      <div class="menuInsBottomIns">
        <a href="http://localhost/ilki/expertise#notre-offre">Notre offre</a>
        <a href="http://localhost/ilki/expertise#conseil">Conseil</a>
        <a href="http://localhost/ilki/expertise#architecture">Architecture</a>
        <a href="http://localhost/ilki/expertise#formation">Formation</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menuIns">
    <div class="menuInsTop">
      <a href="http://localhost/ilki/echangeons">Echangeons</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menuInsBottom" style="display: none;">
      <div class="menuInsBottomIns">
        <a href="http://localhost/ilki/expertise#notre-offre">Notre offre</a>
        <a href="http://localhost/ilki/expertise#conseil">Conseil</a>
        <a href="http://localhost/ilki/expertise#architecture">Architecture</a>
        <a href="http://localhost/ilki/expertise#formation">Formation</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="menuIns">
    <div class="menuInsTop">
      <a href="http://localhost/ilki/contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.menuIns').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).find('.menuInsBottom').css('display', 'block');
});
$('.menuIns').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).find('.menuInsBottom').css('display', 'none');
});
```

CSS:

```
.menuAll {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;  
}
.menuAll a {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    color: #A2B5BE;
    padding: 0px 5px;
}
.menuInsBottom {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 80px;
    display: none;
}
.menuInsBottom a{
    padding: 5px 10px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
.menuInsBottom a:hover{
    background: #ECF0F2;
}
.menuInsBottomIns {
    background: #FFF;
    border:2px solid #A2B5BE;
    text-align: left;
}
.menuIns,
.menuInsTop {
    display: inline;
}
.menuIns {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-top: 50px;  
}
.menuIns:hover {
    color: #000;
}
.menuIns:hover a{
    color: #000;
}
```

I've searched for several questions here but none seems to be the one I'm looking for.

Comment: That's generally how it works, when the mouse leaves the element with the event handler attached, the callback for that event is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer to this question the problem comes from the fact that the child element is positioned absolutely and there is a gap between the menu item and sub-menu.

One way to get around this is to set the CSS for .menuInsBottom to the following:

```
.menuInsBottom {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 65px;
    display: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Fixing the problem by having the padding of the sub menu touch the edge of the link. You can see the result in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucarF/17/)

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the links (a elements) in the parent div are overlapped, so they're no longer functional.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I didn't think of it. But reading your solution to the problem I believe it will work. However you might want to avoid using float. You can set block the bottom menu and the menu link to be block display.

Comment: I updated the solution to account for that issue. The links should work now and the mouseleave/enter work just fine. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll give you the correct answer for this.

Answer (score 2):

If you make some overlap by changing `top:80px` to say `top:70px` you may be able to get into the child before `mouseleave` triggers. Ideally, your mouse is going through an area not outside of the parent in order to reach the child ... you want to avoid that by the 'overlap'.

```
.menuInsBottom {
    .....
    top: 70px;
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/6X5Y7/)

Just so you can see what makes the `mouseleave` to trigger take a look at the following demo that has a border around the parent .... see the gap which is neither in the parent or the child. **Note that the child is outside due to `absolute` positioning ... normally the child would be right inside the parent.**

[**SEE GAP BETWEEN CHILD AND PARENT**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/6X5Y7/1/)

Comment: It's a solution... but I was looking for something more clear, maybe I'm missing something at a JS level.

Comment: The issue is more of a CSS than a JS one. Normally **a child is always in a parent**; however absolute positioning changes the game a little. Please take a look at the second demo I provided. If that is not satisfactory explanation, let us know so.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have the solution... the problem comes with the "display:inline" in the parent element (menuIns). If I use the right combination of "display:block" and "float" I can get the problem solved.